# Dynamic convert rows to columns in sql server whitout aggregate

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot

Hi,

I have this data:

---------------------------------
 |Masterarticle | childarticle   |
 ----------------------------------
 |     12341       |   12345        |
 |     12341       |   12346        |
 |     12341       |   12347        |
 |     12342       |   44875        |
 |     12342       |   44876        |
 ----------------------------------

and this is my expected resultset:

|   12341   |    12342   |
-------------------------
|   12345   |    44875   |
-------------------------
|   12346   |    44876   |
-------------------------
|   12347   |    NULL   |
-------------------------
|   12347   |    NULL   |
-------------------------

I have this, but it shows me only one row, because of the aggregate max(childarticle). Is there any way, to query a dynamic table whitout aggregate?

```
            DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Masterarticle) 
                    from  table 
                    group by Masterarticle

            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select childarticle, Masterarticle
                from table 
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(childarticle)
                for Masterarticle in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: So, what is your expected resultset here? Are those 2 sets of data both in your table?

Comment: give us the expected result you want

Comment: sorry, see above now

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a row_number to the query used for the pivot.

Then the PIVOT will group on that calculated row_number and return more that 1 row.

An example using a temporary table that only lives in the session:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTestTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpTestTable;
create table #tmpTestTable (Masterarticle int, Childarticle int);

insert into #tmpTestTable (Masterarticle, Childarticle) values
(12341, 12345),(12341, 12346),(12341, 12347),
(12342, 44875),(12342, 44876);

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Masterarticle) from  #tmpTestTable group by Masterarticle FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');
--select @cols;

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N'
 from (
    select Masterarticle, Childarticle,
    row_number() over (partition by Masterarticle order by Childarticle) as RN
    from #tmpTestTable
) x
pivot (max(childarticle) for Masterarticle in (' + @cols + N')) pvt';

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Returns:

```
12341  12342
-----  -----
12345  44875
12346  44876
12347  NULL
```

Comment: ok, i can not modify the sql table. But everything from DECLARE works perfect! Many Thanks!

Comment: @Batchechooff Not sure why you would need to modify the sql table.  I merely used a temporary table for demonstration purposes. Since that's easier for others to verify that it works. :)